# KeyError(key) while merging the data frames

Tags: pandas, merge

```py
Input = df=pd.merge(Bx_Users,BX_ratings,on='user_id')
Error = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/91943/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches/MergingwithSummerclothingdataset.py", line 14, in <module>
    df=pd.merge(Bx_Users,BX_ratings,on='user_id')
  File "C:\Users\91943\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 74, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "C:\Users\91943\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "C:\Users\91943\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1005, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
  File "C:\Users\91943\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1560, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'user_id'
```

I tried different ways of fixing the issue. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: show the structure of the 2 df's you are merging.
looks like one or both of them are missing the column `user_id`

Comment: print `Bx_Users.columns` and `BX_ratings.columns` to confirm columns. You must have missing column name `user_id` in one of the dataframe.

Comment: I checked, "User_ID" column is available in both dataframes

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried renaming the column and I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters
rightDataFrame or named Series
Object to merge with.

how{‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}, default ‘inner’
Type of merge to be performed.

left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order.

right: use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; preserve key order.

outer: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically.

inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys.

cross: creates the cartesian product from both frames, preserves the order of the left keys.

New in version 1.2.0.

Comment: It was not easier put the link to the `pd.merge` documentation in the first place?. Anyway I think this doesn't respond to the question properly, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer